# How can I use a .txt file as the license in a WiX installation package?

Tags: wix, wix3

Is it possible to use any other filetype than RTF as the license?  RTF is practically dead, and I'd like to use a format that's readable in a standard text editor (like .txt or .md) instead.

Here's what I'm currently using with an RTF license, which is working correctly:

`<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="..\Eula\EulaText_$(var.Lcid).rtf" />`

If I simply replace the path with a TXT file like so:

`<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="..\Eula\Test.txt" />`

then I get a blank license dialog:

[image]

There doesn't appear to be a `WixUILicenseTxt`

Answer (score 0):

The [ScrollableText Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/scrollabletext-control) the Windows Installer engine provides is a [RICHEDIT control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-rich-edit-controls) in read-only mode.

You can put just text in there (including Markdown) but it will be rendered using rich text rules.

Comment: Any way to do this in a wix project?  I'm currently using `<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="..\Eula.rtf" />` to get that to show up in the pre-built license dialog, but would love to swap it for txt.  Because nuget requires md or txt for the license and WiX requires rtf, I'm currently keeping duplicate copies.

Comment: WiX does not require an `rtf` file. The Windows Installer uses a `RICHEDIT control`. Try using .txt in both places and see if it looks good in both places. Or use .md and know that it will not be formatted as Markdown in the `RICHEDIT control` in the MSI.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you were saying now.  When I tried simply pointing the `WixUILicenseRtf` variable to a text file, I get a blank EULA page.  I've updated the question with that additional info.